# Is this kitchen timer code pythonic?

Tags: python, timer

I've been doing bits and bobs with Python for a few years, but I've never took the time to get feedback on what's pythonic and what's not. In the interest of collaborating more with Python programmers, I'd like to make sure my code follows conventions and idioms that the majority of Pythonistas will recognize.

Please review my Kitchen Timer class for:

- pythonic idioms and conventions
- behavioural correctness (especially around multi-threading and timing precision)
- portability
- readability
- maintainability
- efficiency

Also, if the purpose of the class is unclear from its API and comments, please offer your suggestions for improvement there too.

```
from threading import Timer as TTimer
from time import time
from threading import Lock

class NotRunningError(Exception): pass
class AlreadyRunningError(Exception): pass


class KitchenTimer(object):
    '''
    Loosely models a clockwork kitchen timer with the following differences:
        You can start the timer with arbitrary duration (e.g. 1.2 seconds).
        The timer calls back a given function when time's up.
        Querying the time remaining has 0.1 second accuracy.
    '''

    running = "running"
    stopped = "stopped"
    timeup =  "timeup"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__stateLock = Lock()
        self.state = self.stopped        
        self.__timeRemainingLock = Lock()
        self.timeRemaining = 0

    def start(self, duration=1, whenTimeup=None):
        if self.isRunning():
            raise AlreadyRunningError    
        else:
            self.state = self.running            
            self.timeRemaining = duration
            self._userWhenTimeup = whenTimeup
            self._startTime = self._now()
            self._timer = TTimer(duration, self._whenTimeup)
            self._timer.start()            

    def stop(self):
        if self.isRunning():
            self._timer.cancel()
            self.state = self.stopped
            self.timeRemaining -= self._elapsedTime()
        else:
            raise NotRunningError()

    def isRunning(self):
        return self.state == self.running

    def isTimeup(self):
        if self.state == self.timeup:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @property
    def state(self):
        with self.__stateLock:
            return self._state

    @state.setter
    def state(self, state):
        with self.__stateLock:
            self._state = state

    @property
    def timeRemaining(self):
        with self.__timeRemainingLock:
            if self.isRunning():
                self._timeRemaining -= self._elapsedTime()
            return round(self._timeRemaining, 1)

    @timeRemaining.setter
    def timeRemaining(self, timeRemaining):
        with self.__timeRemainingLock:
            self._timeRemaining = timeRemaining

    def _whenTimeup(self):
        self.state = self.timeup
        self.timeRemaining = 0
        if callable(self._userWhenTimeup):
            self._userWhenTimeup()    

    def _now(self):
        return time()

    def _elapsedTime(self):
        return self._now() - self._startTime
```

Comment: I've just noticed I have two different styles for a predicate. One with explicit True or False, one implicit. Whoops.

Comment: Someone once linked this http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ to me, and I found it very useful when I needed to learn the Python syntax and conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Bugs

1. You have two locks, one protecting `state`, and the other protecting `timeRemaining`. But these locks operate independently. That means that when you update both of these properties:

   ```
   self.state = self.timeup
   self.timeRemaining = 0
   ```

   it would be possible for another thread to run in between these two statements and see `state == timeup` but `timeRemaining != 0`. You need one lock to protect both properties, so that they are updated atomically. See below for some race conditions that are consequences of this bug.
2. The `timeRemaining` property updates the `_timeRemaining` value by subtracting the elapsed time. But this means that if you keep requesting the `timeRemaining` property, it will keep subtracting the elapsed time, giving you nonsense like this:

   ```
   >>> t = KitchenTimer()
   >>> t.start(5)
   >>> t.timeRemaining
   3.2
   >>> t.timeRemaining
   0.6
   >>> t.timeRemaining
   -2.6
   >>> t.timeRemaining
   -6.6
   >>> t.timeRemaining
   -11.3
   >>> t.timeRemaining
   0.0
   ```
3. There's a race condition between the `start` method and the `whenTimeup` method. In `start` you have:

   ```
   if self.isRunning():                  # 1
       raise AlreadyRunningError    
   else:
       self.state = self.running         # 2
       self.timeRemaining = duration     # 3
   ```

   and in `_whenTimeUp` you have:

   ```
   self.state = self.timeup              # 4
   self.timeRemaining = 0                # 5
   ```

   A possible order of execution is 4–1–2–3–5 which would set `state` to `running` and `timeRemaining` to 0.
4. There's a race condition between the `stop` method and the `_whenTimeup` method. In `stop` you have:

   ```
   if self.isRunning():                  # 1
       self._timer.cancel()              # 2
       self.state = self.stopped         # 3
   ```

   and in `_whenTimeUp` you have:

   ```
   self.state = self.timeup              # 4
   ```

   A possible order of execution is 1–4–2–3 which would leave `state` as `stopped` when it ought to be `timeup`.

   (There may well be more race conditions; I haven't looked very hard.)

#### 2. Comments on your code

1. Why "Kitchen" timer? The class doesn't seem to have anything to do with kitchens.
2. There doesn't seem to be any documentation for the methods.
3. Why does the `timeRemaining` method round the result to one decimal place? There doesn't seem to be any explanation of this. It would be more natural to return the actual time remaining.
4. Why do you rename `threading.Timer` as `TTimer`? The name `Timer` doesn't seem to conflict with anything in your code.
5. The Python style guide ([PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) recommends using `lowercase_with_underscores` for method and property names. You're not obliged to follow this guide, but it will make it easier for you to collaborate with other Python programmers.
6. The intended use of private names in Python is to "avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses" but that's not necessary here. So write `_state_lock` instead of `__stateLock` and so on.
7. The `_now` method seems a bit pointless:

   ```
   def _now(self):
       return time()
   ```

   Why not just call `time()`?

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Gareth. This is the best mentoring feedback I've ever received on any code! I'll definitely be using Code Review more often. And I'll update you when I've incorporated your feedback.

Comment: I agree with your race condition examples and I agree that I need to make the internal state of the object change atomically, but before doing that, how can I expose the bug(s) with unit tests?

Comment: Your question about how to make tests that expose race conditions would be a good question for [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) — but see the answers to [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/196105/30159) which are not encouraging.

Comment: I've asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19602535/1224758) specific to this context which I think you can help with...

Comment: For reference the updated code can be found [here](https://github.com/doughgle/pomodoro_evolved/blob/master/pomodoro_evolved/kitchen_timer.py).

Comment: To answer your outstanding questions @gareth; 1, The context helps to understand the behaviour. 3, I'm trying to avoid precision related complexity and this precision is good enough for the context. 5, unittest uses CamelCase for it's methods and I find it easier to read.